# Select using where with multiple element in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following code does not work but I am using is as an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT thing_id
FROM table_of_things
WHERE table_of_things.thing_color, table_of_things.thing_flavor IN 
                          ( SELECT good_color,good_flavor FROM good_things )
```

EDIT: So apparently it wasent apparent from my code to SOME people. I am trying to use to get the things_id from the table_of_things using two criteria from the subquery.

Comment: You need to be more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try using the JOINS between the two tables.....although you need to explain your question a bit more..:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't asked a question but I suspect you need to change your query to the following:

```
SELECT thing_id
FROM table_of_things
WHERE table_of_things.thing_color IN  ( SELECT good_color FROM good_things )
AND table_of_things.thing_flavor  IN  ( SELECT good_flavor FROM good_things )
```

or maybe:

```
SELECT thing_id
FROM table_of_things as tot
INNER JOIN good_things as gt
ON tot.thing_color = gt.good_color AND tot.thing_flavor = gt.good_flavor
```

An in statement can only check one value, not two like you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the IN could only use 1, wanted to see if I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Join**

```
SELECT t.thing_id
FROM table_of_things t
JOIN good_things gt 
ON t.thing_color = gt.good_color 
AND t.thing_flavor =  gt.good_flavor
```

**Using Union**

```
SELECT t.thing_id FROM table_of_things t WHERE t.thing_color IN ( SELECT good_color FROM good_things )
UNION 
SELECT t.thing_id FROM table_of_things t WHERE t.thing_flavor IN ( SELECT good_flavor FROM good_things )
```

**Using EXIST**

```
SELECT t.thing_id FROM table_of_things t 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT good_color,good_flavor FROM good_things)
```